# IE11 replaces Bearer with NTLM in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, token, internet-explorer-11

I have some research on that problem. There are a few answers here too. One of the accepted suggestions was to enable Anonymous access to the application root. I cannot do that because the app only expects Windows Auth. Here what is happening. The initial page loads fine. If I place a request within a few seconds (did not figure out how many seconds) it works fine. But if I wait for about 2 min or maybe even less the request authorization header is replaced with 'NTLM + very long string' and the backend returns 406 "Not acceptable". What is the problem? Why IE is doing that?

Thanks

Update. Here is what actually helped. This code is from my interceptor:

```
service.request = function (config) {
    document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false'); // fixed the problem
    return configureRequest(config);
};
```

Comment: Yes, it is IIS based site, and yes, it can be reproduced on multiple machines. 406 is an application specific code. It means that a request has an invalid token. It is  invalid from application's point of view because 'bearer' was replaced with 'NTLM' which is clearly seen in Network tab.

Comment: Anybody, please help. I am really stuck with this one.

Comment: Is there any way to reproduce this issue on our side to see and test to find any solution or workaround? If yes please try to provide any sample code or detailed steps. We will try to make a test with it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I am not sure about example. It's the whole application. Let me tell you what helped and that might give you an idea. I am updating my question with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what actually helped. This code is from my interceptor:

```
service.request = function (config) {
     document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false'); // fixed the problem
     return configureRequest(config);
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working in Edge. If I use this line Edge will keeps prompting for credentials :(